# HTML: Storing multiple user entries

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

In my HTML I have two pages, 1 is a fitness log and the other is a page to add a new entry to the log. When the user adds a new entry it is saved to local storage and then when the fitness log is loaded, it reads the local storage and puts the information inside of a textbox. This works fine for 1 entry, but when I need to create a second different entry it overwrites the previous. This is because I assume the way I save the user input into local storage.

This is where I save the user input from a form:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Add New Log</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/New Log.css">
  <script src="JavaScript/New Log.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<script type = "text/JavaScript">
function save() {
    // save values into localStorage
    localStorage['Entry Name'] = document.getElementById('eName').value;
    localStorage['Exercise'] = document.getElementById('exercise').value;
    localStorage['Date'] = document.getElementById('date').value;
    localStorage['Start Time'] = document.getElementById('sTime').value;
    localStorage['End Time'] = document.getElementById('eTime').value; 
    localStorage['Calorise Lost'] = document.getElementById('cal').value;   

    alert("Log Entry Saved");

};


</script>

<h1> Add New Log </h1>

<form id="contact-form">
        <label for="entryName">Log entry name:</label>
        <input type="text" id = "eName"  value="" placeholder="Run at the 
park"/>
        <label for="exerciseName">Name of exercise:</label>
        <input type="name" id = "exercise"  value="" placeholder="Jogging"  />
        <div id="line">
         <label> ------------------------------ <span class="required">
</span></label>
         </div>
         <div id="detail">
        <label for="Date">Date: </label>
        <input type="date" id = "date" value="" />
         <label for="startTime">Start Time: </label>
        <input type="time" id = "sTime"  value="" />
        <label for="endTime">End Time: </label>
        <input type="time" id = "eTime" value="" />
        <label for="caloriseLost">Calories Lost: </label>
        <input type="number" id = "cal"  value="" />
       </div>


</form>

<li><a href="Fitness Log.html" onclick ="save()"> Add New Log</a></li>




</body>


</html>
```

This is where I read the local sotrage back to the user in the form of a textbox:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Health and Fitness</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Log.css">


 </head>

 <body>
 <script>


 window.onload = function(){

     var values = document.getElementById("Text1");
for (let [key, prop] of Object.entries(localStorage)) {
  values.value += ` ${key} : ${prop}\n `;
};


}

</script>


<h1> Fitness Log </h1>
<p> Fitness Log keeps track of the exercise you complete and saves it to 
your account.</p> 

<div>
<ul>
     <li><a href="New Log.html"> Add Log</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"onclick 
="window.localStorage.clear();window.location.reload();" > Delete All</a>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>



<textarea id="Text1" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea>
<textarea id="Text2" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea>

</body>


</html>
```

This is the output from the above code:

[image]

The solution I am looking for is that a new entry into local storage is made and then if there is something inside the first text box, load the next entry into textbox 2.

Comment: Hi, what are the contents of `New Log.js`?

Comment: New log is not getting used I apologize for leaving it in

Comment: Is `JQuery` allowed?

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST PART** Where you are creating the log.

First of all before initiating the `function save()` what you need is an array. So create one from scratch if no `localstorage` is present. If there is at least one record in the `localstorage` then put it into that array, like so :

```
if (localStorage.getItem('logs') === null) {
    var currentLogs = [];
} else {
    var currentLogs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('logs'));
}
```

Note that this is just before **save function**

Now you can write your function. But this time instead of one object, you should push this object inside the array we just declared.

```
function save() {
    var currentLog = {
        log_id: localStorage.length + 1,
        entry_name: document.getElementById('eName').value,
        exercise: document.getElementById('exercise').value,
        date: document.getElementById('date').value,
        start_time: document.getElementById('sTime').value,
        end_time: document.getElementById('eTime').value,
        calorise_lost: document.getElementById('cal').value
    };
currentLogs.push(currentLog)
    // save values into localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("logs", JSON.stringify(currentLogs));
    alert("Log Entry Saved");
};
```

**SECOND PART** Where you are showing the logs.

In your **HTML** instead of creating each `textarea tags` Just create an empty div

```
<div id="logTextarea"></div>
```

Now we can access to that **DIV** and create `<textarea>` dynamically and put the data inside

```
window.onload = function(){
var logTextarea = document.getElementById("logTextarea");
    var vals = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('logs'));
    for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
      inputLog = document.createElement("textarea");
      inputLog.id = "logID" + vals[i]['log_id'];
      inputLog.rows = "6";

      inputLog.value = "";
      inputLog.value += "Entry Name : " + vals[i]['entry_name'] + "\n";
      inputLog.value += "Excercise : " + vals[i]['exercise'] + "\n";
      inputLog.value += "Date : " + vals[i]['date'] + "\n";
      inputLog.value += "Start Time : " + vals[i]['start_time'] + "\n";
      inputLog.value += "End Time : " + vals[i]['end_time'] + "\n";
      inputLog.value += "Calorise Lost" + vals[i]['calorise_lost'];

      logTextarea.appendChild(inputLog);
    }
}
```

> It runs exactly as asked, on my computer. If you have questions about it, don't hesitate to ask. Hope this works.